# Conflict library when deploy custom mediator in WSO2 ESB

Tags: java, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I used WSO2 EI 6.4.0. 
I need to write a custom mediator used an external jar, called JAVA_SDK_VXP-2.0.3.jar (com.vpcp.services package).

```
package com.quangnam.example;

import org.apache.synapse.MessageContext; 
import org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractMediator;

import com.vpcp.services.AgencyServiceImp;
import com.vpcp.services.model.GetAgenciesResult;

public class AgenciesListMediator extends AbstractMediator { 

    public boolean mediate(MessageContext context) { 
        getAgenciesList(context);
        return true;
    }

    private void getAgenciesList(MessageContext context) {
        AgencyServiceImp agencyService = new AgencyServiceImp();
        String jsonHeader = "{}";
        GetAgenciesResult getAgenciesResult = agencyService.getAgenciesList(jsonHeader);        
        context.setProperty("agenciesResult", getAgenciesResult.getAgencies());
    }
}
```

The JAVA_SDK_VXP-2.0.3.jar needs to call httpclient-4.5.6.jar. I have a jar as httpclient_4.3.6.wso2v2.jar in {EI-HOME}/wso2/components/plugins. This jar comes with WSO2 EI.

I deployed custom mediator and copy httpclient-4.5.6.jar, JAVA_SDK_VXP-2.0.3.jar to {EI-HOME}/lib folder.
Everything is OK, but when I called the API used the custom mediator, there is an exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.setValidateAfterInactivity(I)V
    at com.vpcp.services.HttpClientFactory.getHttpsClient(HttpClientFactory.java:180)
    at com.vpcp.services.HttpConnection.sendPost(HttpConnection.java:91)
    at com.vpcp.services.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:272)
    at com.vpcp.services.VnptService.execute(VnptService.java:110)
    at com.vpcp.services.AgencyServiceImp.getAgenciesList(AgencyServiceImp.java:37)
    at com.quangnam.example.AgenciesListMediator.getAgenciesList(AgenciesListMediator.java:24)
    at com.quangnam.example.AgenciesListMediator.mediate(AgenciesListMediator.java:16)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.ext.ClassMediator.mediate(ClassMediator.java:94)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:108)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:70)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.Resource.process(Resource.java:364)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:399)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.apiProcess(RESTRequestHandler.java:135)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:113)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:71)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:303)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMessageReceiver.receive(SynapseMessageReceiver.java:92)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:337)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:158)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I started EI server with -DosgiConsole. As the result, I think the JAVA_SDK_VXP-2.0.3.jar called httpclient_4.3.6.wso2v2 not httpclient-4.5.6.jar, so there is no method setValidateAfterInactivity()

```
osgi> packages org.apache.http.impl.conn
org.apache.http.impl.conn; version="4.3.6.wso2v2"<httpclient_4.3.6.wso2v2 [78]>
  JAVA_SDK_VXP_2.0.3_1.0.0 [4] imports
  google-http-client_1.20.0.wso2v1 [68] imports
  solr_5.2.1.wso2v1 [598] imports
  spring.framework_3.2.9.wso2v1 [600] imports
  tomcat_7.0.85.wso2v1 [612] imports
org.apache.http.impl.conn; version="0.0.0"<httpclient_4.2.5.wso2v1_1.0.0 [79]>
org.apache.http.impl.conn; version="0.0.0"<httpclient_4.5.6_1.0.0 [80]>
org.apache.http.impl.conn; version="0.0.0"<httpclient_osgi_4.5.6_1.0.0 [81]>
```

I go to the {EI-HOME}/dropins folder to edit bundle of my external libraries.

Edit MANIFEST.MF of httpclient_4.5.6_1.0.0.jar to

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-SymbolicName: httpclient_4.5.6
Export-Package: org.apache.http.auth,org.apache.http.cookie,org.apache
 .http.cookie.params,org.apache.http.client,org.apache.http.client.met
 hods,org.apache.http.client.params,org.apache.http.client.utils,org.a
 pache.http.client.protocol,org.apache.http.conn,org.apache.http.conn.
 routing,org.apache.http.conn.params,org.apache.http.conn.socket,org.a
 pache.http.conn.ssl,org.apache.http.impl.auth,org.apache.http.impl.co
 okie,org.apache.http.impl.client,org.apache.http.impl.execchain,org.a
 pache.http.impl.conn;version="4.5.6",org.apache.http.client.config,org.apache.http.cl
 ient.entity,org.apache.http.conn.util,org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm
 ,org.apache.http.conn.scheme,org.apache.http.auth.params
Bundle-Name: httpclient_4.5.6
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Bundle-ClassPath: .,httpclient-4.5.6.jar
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
DynamicImport-Package: *
```

Edit MANIFEST.MF of JAVA_SDK_VXP_2.0.3_1.0.0.jar to

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-SymbolicName: JAVA_SDK_VXP_2.0.3
Export-Package: com.vpcp.services,com.vpcp.services.exception,com.vpcp
 .services.model,com.vpcp.services.request,com.vpcp.services.utils
Bundle-Name: JAVA_SDK_VXP_2.0.3
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Bundle-ClassPath: .,JAVA_SDK_VXP-2.0.3.jar
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Import-Package: org.apache.http.impl.conn;version="4.5.6"
DynamicImport-Package: *
```

Result:

```
osgi> update 80
osgi> update 4
osgi> packages org.apache.http.impl.conn
org.apache.http.impl.conn; version="4.3.6.wso2v2"<httpclient_4.3.6.wso2v2 [78]>
  google-http-client_1.20.0.wso2v1 [68] imports
  solr_5.2.1.wso2v1 [598] imports
  spring.framework_3.2.9.wso2v1 [600] imports
  tomcat_7.0.85.wso2v1 [612] imports
org.apache.http.impl.conn; version="0.0.0"<httpclient_4.2.5.wso2v1_1.0.0 [79]>
org.apache.http.impl.conn; version="4.5.6"<httpclient_4.5.6_1.0.0 [80]>
  JAVA_SDK_VXP_2.0.3_1.0.0 [4] imports
org.apache.http.impl.conn; version="0.0.0"<httpclient_osgi_4.5.6_1.0.0 [81]>
```

But nothing has changed. Please help me.

Comment: You could include the required httpclient library into the mediator bundle and not to import the http client from the OSGi references, so the internal (included) library is used

Comment: Please tell me how to include it, I added the dependency of httpclient to mediator pom file.

Comment: please see the doc, http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html look for the `Embed-Dependency` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE

I resolved it. After editing MANIFEST.MF, from {EI-HOME}/lib, I deleted httpclient-4.5.6.jar, JAVA_SDK_VXP-2.0.3.jar and restart EI server.